# :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug after installnig react-native-maps

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, react-native-maps

I install react-native-maps in my Project. Then I run my app in my physical device `react-native run-android` then I got this error. But in my other project which is also have react-native-map it did not get the error. I just created this project yesterday, I downgrade the react native version from `0.57.3` to `0.57.1`, installed babel/runtime and babel/core because some other errors to resolve it.

So this is my error:

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\rnprojects\PracticeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
 "name": "PracticeProject",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
 "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
 "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.0",
 "react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "0.57.1",
"react-native-maps": "^0.22.0"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
"babel-jest": "23.6.0",
"jest": "23.6.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.1",
"react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
 },
 "jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

This is my build.gradle(app) of my project:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.practiceproject"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
   }
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
 }
```

And this line `implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"` is in the red line it means there is something wrong, but I do not know how to do it that is why I posted in Stack Overflow to get some help. Thank you!

Comment: You have to exclude `android.support.v4` from React as you've already mentioned that in gradle

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Where should I put that?